# SAXParseException - Document structures

Tags: java, xml, dom, saxparser

I'm writing an app that is sending/receiving xml.

Messages are generated with DOM and periodically sent to server (once in 2 sec). When getting some message (it depends on some params, but constant for different launches) server responds with an error: `XML document structures must start and end within the same entity` - possibly, end of received message is cut off. Sometimes errors are in a row, sometimes they mix with normal messages.

Messages are formed correctly (otherwise error could be from start). I suppose, in some way it is connected with message length; it is about 9800 symbols on a break.

I also found a post with similar error: [SAXParseException: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306626/saxparseexception-xml-document-structures-must-start-and-end-within-the-same-en), but it differs from mine.

Here it some of the code, may be I am doing something wrong.

**Generating document class:**

```
public class DOMConstructor {

private Element actions;
Document document = null;

DOMConstructor (String key) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    document = documentBuilder.newDocument();
    Element rootElement = document.createElement("request");
    document.appendChild(rootElement);


    Element token = document.createElement("token");
    token.appendChild(document.createTextNode(key));
    rootElement.appendChild(token);


    Element actions = document.createElement("actions");
    rootElement.appendChild(actions);

    this.actions = actions;
}


public StreamResult getResultXml (OutputStream out) throws TransformerException, FileNotFoundException {

    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

    DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);

    StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(out);
    transformer.transform(domSource, streamResult);

    return streamResult;
}


protected void addAction (String fromId, String toId, String droids_num) {      
    Element action = document.createElement("action");
    actions.appendChild(action);

    Element from = document.createElement("from");
    from.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fromId));
    action.appendChild(from);

    Element to = document.createElement("to");
    to.appendChild(document.createTextNode(toId));
    action.appendChild(to);

    Element units = document.createElement("unitscount");
    units.appendChild(document.createTextNode(droids_num));
    action.appendChild(units);
}       
}
```

**Sending xml:**

```
public void sendData (XMLData xml) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, TransformerException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
    conn = new Socket(address, port);       
    OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    xml.sendData(out, true);

}
```

Comment: It seems your XML has some special characters embedded in it.

Comment: are you sending multiple xml messages over the same socket connection?  if so, how do you distinguish messages?  also, do you flush the BufferedOutputStream after you write the xml?

Comment: @Nambari No, all characters are ordinary.

Comment: @jtahlborn No, I create a new socket every time I sendData, so there is one message out and one is taken over connection. Therefore, flush of OutputStream has no effect.

Comment: do you flush the _BufferedOutputStream_, which could still be holding data which has not yet been written to the socket?

Comment: I tried to call flush() at the end of sendData(), but that still had no effect.